# using in memory assembly generated from ICode Compiler to build another source code

Tags: c#

I have an interface and a class that implements it. I am trying to create a unit test that will compile both the interface and the class and see that if there are any errors(if theres none then that would mean the class does implement the interface). I am able to build the interface with no errors but when I try to build the class that implements it it says that the class does not implement the interface. I made sure already that the class does implement the interface so i know that there is something wrong with the way I am trying to compile it on my unit test. I generate the inMemoryAssembly.dll and then try to add it to the parameters when trying to compile the implementation, but that is not working.Any suggestion?

```
 using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("NumberOfFiles")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var serviceReferancepath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\Service References\");
            compileIterface(serviceReferancepath);
            compileImplementation(serviceReferancepath);
        }
        static void compileIterface(string path)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters parametersForInterface = new CompilerParameters();

            parametersForInterface.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Services.Client.dll");
            parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ComponentModel.dll");
            parametersForInterface.OutputAssembly = "inMemoryAssembly.dll";
            StringBuilder interfaceSC = new StringBuilder();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + @"alarm\IActiveEventSource.cs"))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    interfaceSC.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }
            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parametersForInterface, interfaceSC.ToString());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            foreach (CompilerError ce in results.Errors)
            {
                if (ce.IsWarning) continue;
                sw.WriteLine("{0}({1},{2}: error {3}: {4}", ce.FileName, ce.Line, ce.Column, ce.ErrorNumber, ce.ErrorText);
            }
            // If there were errors, raise an exception...
            string errorText = sw.ToString();

        }
        static void compileImplementation(string path)
        {
            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters Parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("inMemoryAssembly.dll");

            Parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            Parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            StringBuilder implementationSC = new StringBuilder();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + @"alarm\implementation\TheActiveEventSource.cs"))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    implementationSC.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }
            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Parameters, implementationSC.ToString());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            foreach (CompilerError ce in results.Errors)
            {
                if (ce.IsWarning) continue;
                sw.WriteLine("{0}({1},{2}: error {3}: {4}", ce.FileName, ce.Line, ce.Column, ce.ErrorNumber, ce.ErrorText);
            }
            // If there were errors, raise an exception...
            string errorText = sw.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

The compileImplementation method, when I run it with a breakpoint I get the following error for the results
UnitTestProject2.alarm.ActiveEventSource' does not implement interface member 'UnitTestProject2.alarm.IActiveEventSource.EventSource

This the implementation code

```
namespace UnitTestProject2.alarm
{
    partial class ActiveEventSource: IActiveEventSource
    {
    }
}
```

---

edit:
I was looking at the warnings but not the actual error that the compiling of the implementation was saying. the string errortext for the compileImplementatation method says that the inMemoryAssembly.dll could not be found

Comment: so ..what does `It's not working mean` can you use the debugger and step through this wealth of code that you have posted..? start with setting breakpoints.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, the second method, when I check the value of results it has a compile error that says UnitTestProject2.alarm.ActiveEventSource' does not implement interface member 'UnitTestProject2.alarm.IActiveEventSource.EventSource

Comment: Have you looked at the actual text that you are compiling (as in, print out the value in the `StringBuilder`)?

Comment: yeah I have, that's the source code, I checked those 2 files already and they give no error, and if they are being read correctly

Comment: It does ***not*** say that "the class does not implement the interface".  It says that the class does not implement ***a specific member of the interface.***  Which is very important, because it means that at least your referenced in-memory assembly is actually referenced correctly.

Comment: So, does your class and your interface both compile successfully when you try to compile them using the C# compiler of your IDE?

Comment: @MikeNakis yes, if I add them to the project and I compile it I get no errors. Also, I checked the parameters when I try to compile the implementation but It shows empty, as in it was not able to find the dll. I don't know if the fact that that the interface and class are all generated from a service reference. Also, the implementation  tries to implement the interface as a partial class, I will edit my question to add the implementation class.